# Why can't I set an exported variable in one file from another in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider these two programs:

testing1.js:

```
'use strict';
var two=require('./testing2');

two.show();
two.animal='Dog';
two.show();
```

testing2.js:

```
'use strict';
var animal='Cat';

function show()
   {
   console.log(animal);
   }

module.exports.animal=animal;
module.exports.show=show;
```

When I run this in Node.js, it prints "Cat Cat".  I expected it to print "Cat Dog". Why did it print "Cat Cat", and how can I make it print "Cat Dog"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `two.animal` and `var animal` are two different variables. The `show` function is always logging the `var animal` that was defined in `testing2.js`

For `testing2.js` I would do something like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    animal: 'Cat',
    show: function () {
        console.log(this.animal); // note "this.animal"
    }
}
```

Then in `testing1.js`:

```
'use strict';

var two = require('./testing2.js');

two.show(); // => Cat
two.animal = 'Dog'; // now replaces 'Cat'
two.show(); // => Dog
```

Comment: this was the exact answer i was typing. +1

Comment: This is a better answer than the one below, in my opinion, because it did seem that OP wanted to set the animal property of an object and have the show method log out whatever it was set to.

Comment: I am accepting this answer even though I had figured it out and answered my own question by the time you answered it.  I had forgotten that Javascript likes to pass Strings by value.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the answer to my own question.  Javascript always passes variables by value, not by reference - of course unless it's an object or function, where the "value" is a reference.  When I copy the *animal* variable to module.exports.animal, it doesn't actually copy that variable, it copies the word "Cat".  Changing that exported variable doesn't affect the original *animal* variable.
Instead of exporting the variable in testing2.js, I created a setter instead. Exporting the setter and using it instead of trying to set *animal* directly made it behave the way I wanted.

testing1.js:

```
'use strict';
var two=require('./testing2');

two.show();
two.setAnimal('Dog');
two.show();
```

testing2.js:

```
'use strict';
var animal='Cat';

function show()
   {
   console.log(animal);
   }

function setAnimal(newAnimal)
   {
   animal=newAnimal;
   }

module.exports.setAnimal=setAnimal;
module.exports.show=show;
```